# Using a regular expression to convert WKT to GeoJSON

Tags: java, mysql, regex, wkt

I obtain data as `WKT` from `mysql`:

```
  POLYGON((148.798828125 -34.37971258046219,
           148.86474609375 -34.10270799317487,
           149.23828125 -34.28899186503752,
           149.2108154296875 -34.601563177240884,
           148.853759765625 -34.51560953848203,
           148.5186767578125 -34.68291096793205,
           148.38134765625 -34.542762387234845,
           148.798828125 -34.37971258046219))
```

I use [this regex](http://rubular.com/r/bNjC1vpgmP) to get all the `paths` within the `polygon`:

```
   (\((-?\d+.\d+\s?-?\d+.\d+,?)+\))*
```

However I find that there is a large number of empty matches in this,how can I tighten this regex for better matches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could avoid the empty matches by changing the last `*` (0 or more) to a `+` (1 or more):

```
(\((-?\d+.\d+\s?-?\d+.\d+,?)+\))+
```

Comment: Thanks man,your answer worked for me,I will accept it as soon as I can.